# Opening a crystal report on click from base Crystal Report Data with crystal viewer

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

So I have two Crystal reports basically related to inventory in SAP B1.

Report 1: Base Report, 
In Report we have thousands of items and their key details

Reports 2: Target Report (Contains Sub Reports as well)
A detailed report for a specific item.

What I am trying to do?

Basically I want to have a link on "ItemCode" of the base report which when clicked should Trigger the target report for which parameter value is Clicked "ItemCode"

I have tried to link the report as a subreport in the base reports detail section but the sub-report can not be used inside subreport.

I hope I was able to explain the situation. 
Please find the attached Screenshots for better understanding.
[image: BASE Report Design]

[image: Trget Report Design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't move the link to the main report, One of the 3rd-party viewers listed [here](https://kenhamady.com/productlinks/default.html#viewers) can do this. You would need to add a formula that tells the viewer what report to launch and what parameters to pass to it when the section or formula are double-clicked.